# Discord.py Enabling Intents for on_member_join Event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am fixing an old bot from before the intents changes were made and I am trying to just do a simple on_server_join Event but it isn't working, I am not getting any error and assume that this is caused by an issue with intents. I have enabled both privileged intents in the developer portal and tried to implement it into my code however it still isn't functioning correctly.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='-', intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(751225399798923315)
    print("Person Joined")
    await channel.send("Welcome!")



client.run('Token')
```

Here is a sample of the code any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You only enabled `intents.messages`, you need `intents.members` for any `on_member_*` event. Also I suggest you simply enabling default intents + `intents.members` and everything should be working fine.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='-', intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)